# Sort titles with localCompare

Tags: javascript, node.js, eleventy

Using Eleventy as static site generator am unable to figure out how to sort titles in certain alphabet (in my case, Latvian, lv). [Documentation related sorting](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/#sorting)

So far script below works for English.

```
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("postsDescending", (collection) =>
    collection.getFilteredByGlob("src/posts/*.md").sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.data.title > b.data.title) return 1;
      else if (a.data.title < b.data.title) return -1;
      else return 0;
    })
  );
```

In my take I try the localeCompare, but getting error `collection.getFilteredByGlob(...).from is not a function`

```
const alphabet = ['a','ā','b','c','č','d','e','ē','f','g','ģ','h','i','ī','j','k','ķ','l','ļ','m','n','ņ','o','p','r','s','š','t','u','ū','v','z','ž'];
    eleventyConfig.addCollection("postsDescending", function(collection) {
        return collection.getFilteredByGlob("src/posts/*.md").from(alphabet).sort(function(a, b) {
           return a.localeCompare(b, 'lv', { sensitivity: 'base' });
        });
    });
```

Needless to say am beginner in Javascript ... Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think there's a `.from()` method available? [`getFilteredByGlob`](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/#getfilteredbyglob(-glob-)) returns a standard JavaScript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thanks for looking into issue. Got it done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I am able solve this by myself.

```
  eleventyConfig.addCollection("postsDescending", (collection) =>
    collection.getFilteredByGlob("src/posts/*.md").sort((a, b) => {
return a.data.title.localeCompare(b.data.title, 'lv', { sensitivity: 'base' });
    })
  );
```